# KDE Connect detects phones but won't detect other computers

Tags: kde-connect

I have two desktop with Kubuntu and one smartphone, all are equipped with kdeconnect.

Until Kubuntu 20.04 all devices were paired and each one could see the other.

Since Kubuntu 20.10, desktops can see the smartphone, the smartphone can see both the desktops, but one desktop can't see the other desktop and vice-versa.

I tried to purge kdeconnect, same result.

One curious thing: if I try to search for new devices from one desktop, it seems to find the other one, as for an instant its name shows in the list, but it disappears immediately!

**EDIT:**

I'm able to pair two desktop (Kubuntu 20.10 - let's say PC1 and Kubuntu 20.04 - let's say PC2) in my Home network. When I go to my company network, I can't pair my desktop PC1 (same as above) with another Kubuntu 20.10 (let's say PC3).
No firewall on both PC1 and PC3, no firewall on the Network.
On the same Company Network, PC1 and PC3 paired correctly until Kubuntu 20.04.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with multiple connected desktops in this application?  KDE Connect is for connecting your **phone** to your desktop.  Some of the documentation uses the term "all devices" but it seems to me in context that it means mobile devices, not other computers/laptops. All of the features have to do with mobile phones/tablets. There are myriad of ways to connect two computers: this software is aimed at connecting your phone. See the documentation: https://userbase.kde.org/KDEConnect

Comment: The only part of the documentation that even suggests troubleshooting the connection between two computers is the sub-topic "[I have two devices running KDE Connect on the same network, but they can't see each other](https://userbase.kde.org/KDEConnect#I_have_two_devices_running_KDE_Connect_on_the_same_network.2C_but_they_can.27t_see_each_other)".

Comment: Do you have firewall on the one which is not working properly. I had this type of issue coz my firewall was interrupting the process. Try excluding the ip address from the firewall if so

Comment: No firewall.
Read ALOUD: before 20.10 it was working PERFECTLY as expected, and my two desktop detected each other on kdeconnect

Comment: @Nmath: From the documentation you linked: *While a typical configuration might include one computer and one phone, it's also possible to pair two computers instead.*

Comment: I found out that this is caused by some certification validation error. Installing `openssl-1.1.1h` solves this issue, but I'm not recommending that, as this version is not supported by Ubuntu and installing it may have some side effects. I won't post it as an answer here for that exact reason.

Comment: @GwynBleidD why is it working on 20.04?

Comment: I have no idea... maybe certs weren't validated in older versions of KDE Connect?

Comment: @GwynBleidD anyway, can you tell me where did you "find out"?

Comment: I've just recompiled the `kdeconnectd` daemon with debug output enabled, started it instead the system version and googled the error I've seen on the screen.

Comment: @GwynBleidD can you post here the error too?

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to GwynBleidD I could solve.
Appearently there was some certification validation error. Installing openssl-1.1.1h from [https://launchpad.net/~savoury1/+archive/ubuntu/encryption?field.series_filter=groovy](https://launchpad.net/%7Esavoury1/+archive/ubuntu/encryption?field.series_filter=groovy) solves this issue.
It will definitely solved in 21.04.