# KDEConnect Kubuntu 20.10 "mystery"

Tags: kubuntu

I have used KDEConnect for years now (up to Kubuntu 20.04), more or less without problems. Now, since additionally installing Kubuntu 20.10 (multi-boot) on the laptop, the exact same Android phone with the same software release does not connect to my laptop anymore, when I boot into 20.10. Under 20.04 everything still works o.k. No firewall is active in either 20.04 or 20.10. Kubuntu 20.10. doesn't recognize the phone. I wonder what's wrong. I suspect some network definition in 20.10, but haven't got a clue as to what it might be. Any hints would be much appreciated.
Regards from (very cold) snowy Austria.
H. Stoellinger

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of: [KDE Connect detects phones but won't detect other computers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1295440/kde-connect-detects-phones-but-wont-detect-other-computers)

See if suggested solution solve your issue too.

Other reports:

https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=168955

https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=429690

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kdeconnect/+bug/1907786

Comment: Those topics describe another situation.

Comment: @hstoellinger See if suggested solution here solve your issue too: https://askubuntu.com/a/1319494/32230